# What is meant by "q-generalisation"?

Tags: continued-fractions, q-analogs

I was reading Prof Gaurav Bhatnagnar, "How to prove Ramanujan q-continued fractions", on the first page he mentions:
$$\text{the q-generalisation of } \\
 1+1+1 \cdots + 1 = n \\
\text{is } 1+q+q^2+ \cdots + q^{n-1} = \frac{1-q^n}{1-q}
$$
Which turns out to be the geometric series when $q < |1|$. What does a q-generalisation mean, I have noticed in several papers authors make reference to $q-\text{fraction}$, or varying $q-""$ terms, is this exactly the same as above, a geometric sequence of some sort?

Comment: Hi Nishi, welcome to MSE. Is it plausibly this: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Analog.html ?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen oh I see now, because the polynomial can be factored out in the geometric expression $(1-q^n)=(1-q)(q^{n-1}+ \cdots + 1)$, which cancels out the denominator, and for $q \to 1$ we get the expression

Comment: See the tag I just added,